# Struct declaration in C

Tags: c, struct, forward-declaration

I have a simple program in pure C, for reading records from file and putting the into linked list. I am **not allowed to use global variables.** Program looks like this:

```
Here are some includes
Some #defines

Function headers for list manipulation:
 void add_item(Record * p, LL * ll);
 void print_all(LL * ll);
 void load(LL * ll);
 ...

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {

        // Sample struct defining one record
        typedef struct Record
        {
            char sign[10];
            long int isbn;
            char name[100];
            char authors[100];
            long int date;
            int id;
            struct Record * next;
        } Record;

        // Information about linked list (LL)
        typedef struct LL
        {
            Record * HEAD;
        }LL;

        // create new Linked List
        LL * ll = (LL *) malloc(sizeof(LL));

        // init 
        ll->HEAD = NULL;

        // Some other work with ll, record ...
}

// now functions its self

// add item p into ll
void add_item(Record * p, LL * ll)
{
    if (ll->HEAD == NULL)
    {
        ll->HEAD = p;
        ll->HEAD->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Record * cur = ll->HEAD;

        while(cur->next != NULL)
            cur = cur->next;
        cur->next = p;
    }
}

void print_all(LL * ll)
{
    if (!ll->HEAD)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "ll->HEAD is NULL...");
        return;
    }

    Record * cur = ll->HEAD;

    while(cur)
    {
        printf("%s\n", cur->name );
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

// other functions
```

Now when I compile with gcc on my Ubuntu 12.04 I get:

```
project.c:20:15: error: unknown type name ‘Record’
project.c:20:27: error: unknown type name ‘LL’
project.c:21:16: error: unknown type name ‘LL’
project.c:22:11: error: unknown type name ‘LL’
project.c:145:15: error: unknown type name ‘Record’
project.c:145:27: error: unknown type name ‘LL’
project.c:162:16: error: unknown type name ‘LL’
project.c:182:11: error: unknown type name ‘LL’
```

How can I let the compiler know of `struct Record` and `struct LL` before function headers, when structs its self and declared in main()?

Comment: Don't declare and define them in `main`! Use a header for that.

Comment: Type declarations are not global variables!

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

The declarations must be visible from the same level that the functions are declared in.

Move the struct declarations to before the list function prototypes.

Or add a pre-declaration:

```
typedef struct Record Record;
```

as long as the list functions are only dealing with pointers (`Record *`), that should work.